# Using Repository method in controller (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use repository method to get all data from DB.

Here is the code of it:

```
      public class ExperienceRepository
    {
        private readonly ToSeeDatabaseContext _context;
        public ExperienceRepository(ToSeeDatabaseContext context) 
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public List<Experience> GetAllExperiences()
        {
            return _context.Experience.ToList();
        }
}
```

I need to call `GetAllExperience` from controller.

So at first I need to declare repo as private property

I do it like this

```
 private ExperienceRepository _exprepo = new ExperienceRepository();
```

But it says, it need

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' of 'ExperienceRepository.ExperienceRepository(ToSeeDatabaseContext)' TooSeeWeb   C:\Users\EugeneSukhomlyn\source\Workspaces\TooSee\Too See Web\Too See Web\Too See Web\Controllers\ExperienceController.cs   14  Active

How I can solve it?

Comment: Pass it an instance of `ToSeeDatabaseContext`...

Comment: Are you using dependency injection?

Comment: Yes, It's DI@Sefe

Comment: DI and `new` don't work together.

Comment: So how I can  pass it as instance?`private ExperienceRepository _exprepo;` like this?  @CodeCaster

Comment: That's basic C# syntax, try reading a tutorial or two. That'd be `new ExperienceRepository(new ToSeeDatabaseContext())`. Or add `ExperienceRepository` to your controller's constructor as a parameter and let your DI container inject that.

Comment: So it would be like this in controller 
`private ExperienceRepository _repo;

        public ExperienceController(ExperienceRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }`? @CodeCaster

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using dependency injection, the preferred way would be to inject the DB context to the repository.

You probably have already code similar to this in the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup.cs` file (or in the place where you configure your service collection if you are not using ASP.NET Core) to set up the context for dependency injection (if you don't you should add it):

```
services.AddDbContext<ToSeeDatabaseContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ToSeeDatabaseContext")));
```

Since your experience repository already accepts `ToSeeDatabaseContext`, it is already ready for dependency injection. Now you have to inform the DI framework about `ExperienceRepository`, so that it can inject it to its consumers. So in `ConfigureServices` you add:

```
services.AddTransient<ExperienceRepository, ExperienceRepository>();
```

Now can use dependency injection whenever you want to need the repository. In your consumer (eg. an ASP.NET page) you can use constructor injection to get a repository:

```
class MyExperienceConsumer {
    private ExperienceRepository _exprepo;
    public MyExperienceConsumer(ExperienceRepository exprepo) {
        _exprepo = exprepo;
    }
}
```

If your consumer is an ASP.NET page controller, this is all you need to do, since the MVC framework will create the controller for you and use DI to give you the repository. If you need to instantiate the consumer yourself you need to do so with the help a service provider from the DI framework, so that it can do its magic (assuming you have a service collection). When you use `ActivatorUtilities`, the DI framework will inject the repository into the constructor:

```
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
MyExperienceConsumer consumer =
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyExperienceConsumer>(serviceProvider);
```

In any case, you can use the DI framework to do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ExperienceRepository` class have one constructor that requires a `ToSeeDatabaseContext` as parameter.

You are trying to create a instance `ExperienceRepository` with no parameters. The compiler can't find a constructor which doesn't take any parameters, producing the compiler error.

Comment: So as I understood, I can add it into Controller constructor like this

`private ExperienceRepository _repo;

        public ExperienceController(ExperienceRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }`?

Comment: Yes i think theres no problem.